# Issue with multidimensional arrays/ arraylist of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to write a program to print all possible combinations of 28 variables that can be either 1 or -1 using a somewhat roundabout method, but the program isn't working. Specifically, I'm using an arraylist to store the solutions, but the stored arrays seem to be changing without my telling them to. I also tried a multidimensional array with the same result. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
    int[] vals = new int [28]; 
    Arrays.fill(vals, 1);
    ArrayList <int[]> solutions = new  ArrayList<int[]> (756);
    long c=0; //counter
    int ns=0; //number of solutions found

    while (ns<756){
        c++;
        for(int i=0;i<28;i++){
            if (c%(i+1)==0){
                vals[i]*=-1;
            }
        }
        boolean unique = true;
        for(int i=0;i<ns;i++){
            if(Arrays.equals(vals, solutions.get(i)) ){
                unique = false;
            }
        }
        if(unique==true){
            solutions.add(vals);
            ns++;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<756;i++){
        System.out.println( "Solution "+ i);
        for(int j=0;j<28;j++){
            System.out.println("1: " + solutions.get(i)[j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by program not working

Comment: You're storing the same array over and over again, so of course any change you make through one "view" would be visible from the others.

Comment: An array in Java is an object, and therefore `vals` is an object reference.  Every time you say `solutions.add(vals)`, you are adding a reference to that same array to the `ArrayList`; you are not making a copy of the array.  Look at the [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) methods.

Comment: @ajb that should be an answer

Comment: Side note: don't use `if(unique==true)`; instead use `if(unique)`.

Answer (score 3):

An array in Java is an object, and therefore `vals` is an object reference.  Every time you say `solutions.add(vals)`, you are adding a reference to that same array to the `ArrayList`; you are not making a copy of the array.

The `Arrays` class has some static `copyOf` methods to copy arrays for you.  This should work, but I haven't tested it:

```
solutions.add(Arrays.copyOf(vals, vals.length));
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to write a program to print all possible combinations of 28 variables that can be either 1 or -1.

```
final int vars = 28;

for (int i = 0; i < (1 << vars); i++) {
    int temp = i;
    for (int j = 0; j < vars; j++) {
        System.out.print((temp % 2 == 0 ? "-1" : "1"));
        System.out.print(' ');
        temp = temp / 2;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```